# derby.js How can I query using $skip and $limit on a sorted collection?

Tags: derbyjs, racerjs

Sorry if this is a dump question but I cannot figure it out.

As collections grow in size, it become convenient to render a portion of the data.  For that we can something like

```
model.query('items', { $skip: 30, $limit: 30 })
```

but what if we want to do that on a filter or a sort?    I have tried

```
model.query('items', { $skip: 30, $limit: 30 }, { creation_time: -1})
```

to mimic MongoDB `.find()`.

I haven't find a way to do a fetch/query on filters.  Of course I don't want to slice after `.get()` since that would be problematic on large collections.  I tried to use a `ref()` on filter with no success.  Does someone know a recipe on how to handle those situations?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I hope .fetch() hold a cursor and wait for .get() to retrieve data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model.query('items', { $skip: 30, $limit: 30, $orderby: {creation_time: -1}})
```

Comment: Thanks!  That looks so obvious now.